# android - center checkbox in button

Tags: android, button, checkbox

I have the below code, it is a checkbox and button on opposite ends. I want to keep it on opposite ends, but i want the checkbox (along with its text) to come at the middle of the button height. 
As is , the checkbox comes on top of button height

```
  <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/rememberCheckBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
        android:text="@string/remember_choice"
        android:textSize="@dimen/dux_textSizeSmaller" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submitBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="@string/submit" />

     </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post your proper xml file

Answer (score 0):

Use this updated XML. I think you will get your result...

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/rememberCheckBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/submitBtn"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/submitBtn"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="@string/remember_choice"
    android:textSize="@dimen/dux_textSizeSmaller" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/submitBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:text="@string/submit" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use this:

```
 android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/submitBtn"
```

In your code:

```
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/rememberCheckBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/submitBtn"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="@string/remember_choice"
        android:textSize="@dimen/dux_textSizeSmaller" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add android:gravity = "center" to the layout which holds your CheckBox and The Button. That simple. Happy coding :)